# Java variable shows value of 'NaN' but var == Double.NaN is false, why?

Tags: java, double, nan

I have the code below:

```
sim = top / bottom;

if(sim == Double.NaN) {
    System.out.println("sim is NaN");
} else {
    System.out.println(sim);
}
```

For some values in my program, `top / bottom` is `0.0 / 0.0` which should be equal to Double.NaN but when I stop at a breakpoint after this section the output shows 'NaN' -i.e. the value of `sim` rather than 'Sim is NaN'.

Why does my test for `sim == Double.NaN` return false if I see it as 'NaN' in the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for `NaN` only via `Double.isNan()`:

```
if (Double.isNaN(sim)) {
  // is Nan
} else {
  // not nan
}
```

On first thoughts that is not intiutive, you have to know it.
The reason behind it, is that this is specified by IEEE Floating Point standard.

You can argument:
`NaN` is not a number, it can be anything but not a number, so two `NaN` cannot be compared to be equal.
For example = 0.0 / 0.0 is NaN; and sqrt(-1) is NaN, too. But that values cannot be compared to be the same.

Additional reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: Actually, there is another way: `Double.compare()`

Comment: Another way is to check if `sim == sim` produces a value of `false`, because a `NaN` is the only value for which a variable would not be equal to itself.

Comment: @wprl: That's true, but use of such a form could cause problems if code were ported into a language whose default comparison operator implements an equivalence relation [much more useful than IEEE behavior in data-processing contexts].

Comment: @supercat honestly, I think there are bigger problems than portability, and don't recommend using that approach, but mentioned it for thoroughness :)

Answer (score 5):

That's because nothing is equal to `NaN`, not even `NaN` itself.  This is specified in the [JLS, Section 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> - If either operand is NaN, then the result of == is false but the result of != is true.
>
> Indeed, the test x!=x is true if and only if the value of x is NaN.
>
> The methods Float.isNaN and Double.isNaN may also be used to test whether a value is NaN.

To test for `NaN`, you must [`Double`'s `isNaN` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN(double)).

```
if (Double.isNaN(sim)) {
```